# Autohotkey - Undo entire macro instead of single commands (Windows 7)

Tags: autohotkey

I tried searching for an answer beforehand but didn't find what I was looking for.  Apologies in advance if this has been answered before.

I do some web work and created a macro in AHK that binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to the HTML equivalent of adding bold tags around a text selection.

The flow is:
cut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>), type `<b>`, paste cut text (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), type `</b>`.

The macro runs fine, but sometimes I want to undo it.  However, whenever I press Undo (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>), I'm left pressing the command 4 times, with each press reverting 1 of the commands posted above.

Is there a better way to write my AHK macro so that I'm able to undo the entire macro in 1 keypress?  Any tips would be great. For Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

I've added the macro below.

```
^+b::
{
SendInput ^x
SendInput <b>
SendInput ^v
SendInput </b>
return
}
```

Edit:  & #60; is the hmtl equiv on '<', but I was worried that this post would convert the HTML tags instead of showing the characters.  Fixed.

Sorry about that, I tend to use a combination of notepad, notepad++, internet explorer to access a CMS. –

I think adding a delay and rewriting the AHK macro in the following way has solved my issue.  Thanks for the help!

^+b:: 
clipboard = 
SendInput ^x
ClipWait,1
if ErrorLevel 
{
    MsgBox, The attempt to copy text onto the clipboard failed.
    return
}
SendInput < b >%clipboard% < /b>
return

Comment: It would be nice if you did tell which HTML editor you use...

Comment: Why not just make a hotkey that does undo four times?

Comment: The only problem with making a macro that did undo four times is that it would be limited only to this specific macro (or a macro containing 4 commands).  I was planning to create more macros with varying n number of commands, but felt this example would be easy to troubleshoot.  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
^+b::
{
Clipboard =
SendInput ^c
ClipWait, 1
Clipboard = <b>%Clipboard%</b>
SendInput ^v
return
}
```

Because the only thing you are doing is a paste, undoing this will undo both of the bold tag.  The clipboard edits are not registered as an "undo" action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
^+b::
Click, 2 ; Highlight current word
Send, ^x
ClipWait, 1 ; ADDED to wait for clipboard
SendInput, <b>^v<`/b>
Return

!b::
Send, ^{z 4}
Return
```

or

```
!b::
Send, "command to search backwards" for </b>
Send, {Del}
Send, "command to search backwards" for <b>
Send, {Del}
Return
```

or

```
!b::
Send, {Home}+{end}  ; [Home] then [Shift][End] to highlight current line
Send, ^h ; Or any other command to start find/replace
Send, <b>^v<`/b>{Tab}^v{Enter} ; or what is required to replace in current section only...
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I like the idea of the 2nd post, but was hoping there was a certain way I could write my initial bold tag AHK script so that Windows interprets the macro as a single command.

Comment: I was playing around w/ trying to do everything in 1 line and this sort of works, since I can undo the paste with tags in 1 Undo, but seems like the clipboard might take a second or 2 to update since i'm missing some of my highlighted text.

Maybe i can add a delay to help.

^+b:: 
SendInput ^x<b>%clipboard%</b>
return

Comment: First the clipboard does have a delay. In order to solve that you need to add a line clipwait (see above). The other way to "undo" the change is to highlight the whole line and do a find replace of the end string and original string.